# Resurrecting Visual C++ 9.0 application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I've been handed an ancient C++ application and asked to see if I can get it building and running again.  I first tried building it using Visual Studio 2022 and ran into a lot of problems, so thought I would try building it in the environment it was used to.

The VCPROJ starts with this:

```
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9.00"
    Name="FsxApp"
    ProjectGUID="{D0B8B3A6-3037-46F2-93D2-40318F591EEE}"
    RootNamespace="FsxApp"
    Keyword="MFCProj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="131072"
    >
```

Looking up Visual C++ 9.0 in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), it says that version maps to "Visual Studio 2008 9.0" so I installed Visual Studio 2008.  For some reason, Visual Studio can't find the files that are right in front of it so I had to add `$(ProjectDir)` to the "Additional Include Directories".

Now, VS complains because it can't find `afxwin.h` so I added the path of my modern MFC folder, and then it couldn't find `winsdkver.h` and `winapifamily.h`, and I found those in subfolders of a folder titled "Windows Kits" that I added to the list.

And now it's complaining because

```
#if (WINVER < 0x0501)
#error MFC does not support WINVER less than 0x0501.  Please change the definition of WINVER in your project properties or precompiled header.
#endif
```

and sure enough, my stdafx.h says

```
#ifndef WINVER                  // Allow use of features specific to Windows 95 and Windows NT 4 or later.
#define WINVER 0x0500           // Windows 2000 or later. (Necessary to use GetTitleBarInfo())
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT            // Allow use of features specific to Windows NT 4 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500     // Windows 2000 or later.
#endif                      

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS          // Allow use of features specific to Windows 98 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0500   // Windows 2000 or later.
#endif
```

and if I change all of those to 0x0501, it is very unhappy:

```
winnt.h(7063) : warning C4163: '_InterlockedExchangeAdd8' : not available as an intrinsic function
winnt.h(7349) : warning C4163: '__cpuidex' : not available as an intrinsic function
atltrace.h(92) : error C2065: 'nullptr' : undeclared identifier
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2159: more than one storage class specified
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX' to 'volatile int'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX' to 'int'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX' to 'int'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX' to 'int'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX' to 'volatile int'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX' to 'int'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2446: '!=' : no conversion from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX' to 'int'
atlwinverapi.h(714) : error C2040: '!=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX'
atlwinverapi.h(716) : error C2100: illegal indirection
atlwinverapi.h(716) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 9 arguments
atlcore.h(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'type_traits': No such file or directory
```

which isn't surprising at all, when one grabs random include folders.

So then I wondered if I could find the correct version of MFC.  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library), the MFC in use during Visual Studio 2008 was mfc90.dll but if you google "download mfc90.dll" you get a bunch of questionable links, and those that look semi-possible just have the DLLS, not the H files.

Is finding an old version of MFC my best bet?  Is there some other way to get an old application building?

Comment: `Now, VS complains because it can't find afxwin.h so I added the path of my modern MFC folder`. I predict this is your problem. Try finding an old version of MFC? And then reset your macros back to 0x0500

Comment: MFC should be installed with Visual Studio. It might be an optional component. Run the VS setup, and ensure you install the MFC component. You need the version that ships with Visual Studio. It might be part of the Windows SDK. Not really sure, I never use MFC. If you can't find it in the VS installer, then check what version of the Windows SDK this version of VS targets by default and download that from Microsoft.

Comment: Here is what I would try: Create a new MFC application with MSVS. copy all source ,header and resource files except stdafx.* into the new project folder (overwriting = yes). Drag and drop those files into solution explorer. Try to build. May fail though. MSVS may use something other than stdafx-files.

Comment: I wouldn’t even try to get it building the way you’re headed. I obviously can’t see the code but I would take it apart pice by piece and bring it into a brand new project and write tests for each part. Getting the new code and tests passing before moving on to another piece of the code.

Comment: MFC isn't a separate download. It's part of Visual Studio. While it isn't *strictly* dependent on the Visual Studio version it is bundled with, there's a lot of dependencies and build system minutiae to make it practically dependent. You'll have to install MFC along with the version of Visual Studio you're using (2008).

Comment: **It comes with all editions other than Express. In other words, it is not free.** [What version of VS 2008 C++ has MFC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5de9d243-c111-4ad3-8c63-4ee3ff84b21d/what-version-of-vs-2008-c-has-mfc?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: While I have not specifically converted a VS2008 project to VS2022, I have done so in many cases and never had troubles with it, VS always converted it successfully. First step, make sure MFC is installed (try creating a new project and check if MFC is offered as an option), install it if needed, as @paddy suggested; it's an option, you have to run the Visual Studio Installer to add it (as far as I can recall it's not initially installed), better install the sources too (sometimes you have to look into there to check the implementation).

Comment: Check folder eg C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include, MFC include files are named afx*.h. The (converted) project should compile with the default include, lib etc paths, no need to set them again, esp set to hardcoded paths. Clean the project before attempting compiling it. Your project will be using the new MFC version (VS2008/VC++9.0 is no longer supported anyway), and some minor code changes may be required as well. Do NOT download VC redist DLLs from such sites please!